# How can I break a for loop in jinja2?

Tags: python, for-loop, jinja2

How can I break out of a for loop in jinja2?

my code is like this:

```html
<a href="#">
{% for page in pages if page.tags['foo'] == bar %}
{{page.title}}
{% break %}
{% endfor %}
</a>
```

I have more than one page that has this condition and I want to end the loop, once the condition has been met.

Comment: there is an extension for that : [extensions/#loop-controls](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#loop-controls)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can't use `break`, you'd filter instead. From the Jinja2 [documentation on `{% for %}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for):

> Unlike in Python it’s not possible to break or continue in a loop. You can however filter the sequence during iteration which allows you to skip items. The following example skips all the users which are hidden:
>
> ```
> {% for user in users if not user.hidden %}
>     <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
> {% endfor %}
> ```

In your case, however, you appear to only need the *first* element; just filter and pick the first:

```
{{ (pages|selectattr('tags.foo', 'eq', bar)|first).title }}
```

This filters the list using the [`selectattr()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#selectattr), the result of which is passed to the [`first` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#first).

The `selectattr()` filter produces an iterator, so using `first` here will only iterate over the input up to the first matching element, and no further.

Comment: This is not always a good approach. For example, I have one case where there's a class that pulls data from somewhere else and delivers it (through an iterator) on request. If I want to show only the first 25 elements, forcing my code to iterate through all, say, 500 and just filter them out from the display is highly inefficient.

Comment: @Canuck: it is up to your view to then provide the template with a smaller dataset.

Comment: @Canuck: the `|first` filter on the other hand will ensure that not the whole dataset is iterated over; `selectattr()` uses iteration, it doesn't produce a whole new list, so `first` only will require iteration *up to the first matching element*.

Comment: @Canuck: I'm not sure that this deserved downvoting however; your scenario is quite different from the one in the question here. If you have a large dataset and you need only the first 25 elements, either have whatever calls the template limit that dataset, or try using `slice()` and using only the first batch.

Comment: This one doesn't work in Django??? At least in my case it complains that `for` format should be `for x in y` only

Comment: @holms: Jinja is not the same template engine as the Django template engine.

Comment: {{ (pages|selectattr('tags.foo', 'eq', bar)|first).title }} What if there is no element found with condition, will this fail? when trying to access 'title'? Do we need a condition before accessing the title attribute?

Comment: @SatyamRaikar no, because unless you explicitly have disabled this Jinja2 will produce an [*undefined* object that renders as an empty string](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables) when the select fails or there is no title attribute.

Answer (score 26):

**Break** and **Continue** can be added to Jinja2 using the loop controls extension.
[Jinja Loop Control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/extensions/#loop-controls)
Just add the extension to the jinja environment.

```
jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.loopcontrols'])
```

as per [sb32134 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150273/how-can-i-break-a-for-loop-in-jinja2#comment38207715_22150273)

Answer (score 13):

But if you for some reason need a loop you can check the loop index inside for-loop block using "loop.first":

```
{% for dict in list_of_dict %} 
    {% for key, value in dict.items() if loop.first %}
      <th>{{ key }}</th>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: got a headache but it worked with "loop.first"
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set break = False %}
{% for item in items %}
  {% if not break %}
    {% if item.name == 'target' %}
      {# do action before break #}
      {% set break = True %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

this is considered literally make the native jinja2 break that can added in any example of jinja2 not just specific case with check, no topic answer provided the way to make break statement for jinja2 they answer with code example to this question and if i used their code to make a break in jinja2 copy paste will not work as this answer is not how make break , it how break this case only thats why i added my answer, all you need usually is replace the `item.name == 'target'` with your condition or just break the first, my target with way like the native way to add break jinja2 not just answer this quest `if loop.index==1`  what if i need break if db.row.id == 2 or other diffrent cases, then you need my example also it help not repeat all code as other solutions require repeat action on all if check and diffrent actions needed now u can just {% set break = True %} as it break keyword native that was my target when make this.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use something like this.

```
{% set ns = namespace(matched = 0) %}
{% for location in locations %}
{%   for range in locations[location] %}
{%     if range | network_in_usable( ansible_default_ipv4.address ) and not ns.matched == 1 %}
{%       set ns.matched = 1 %}
{{       location }}
{%     endif %}
{%   endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Using a namespace variable we loop through until we find a match if variable = 0, as soon as we find a match, change the variable to 1 and your loop effectively stops.

I used to have another if statement at the bottom outside of the loop that then said if ns.matched == 0, print a default value . . . but I opted to remove that so that the ansible playbook could give a default value instead.

For anyone interested in the code above.. we use a template to lookup the location code based on the IP address.

So the variable:
`{"locations": {"rno_openstack":["10.8.0.0/24"],"rno": ["10.8.0.0/14"]}}`

You can see if we had 10.8.0.1 that we would return `rno_openstack` but the loop will stop so that we don't also return `rno` since the IP also falls in to that CIDR range.

and we call the template with
`"{{ lookup('template', 'lookup_location.j2') | replace('\n', '') }}"`